# Modificar una variable global desde una función

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Tengo un problema. Anteriormente me ayudaron a solucionar un problema con unas funciones; fue muy útil, arreglé ese problema pero llegué a otro, por supuesto jaja.

Para dar un valor al terminar la aplicación (cuestiones de la función de la app) necesito darle un valor a `n` desde dentro de la función, pero me dice que la tengo que definir. Pero si la defino al imprimir el valor me da el valor que definí, como si no hubiera servido de nada.

He tratado de hacer global la variable pero sigue diciendo que la variable no está definida.

Esta es la parte del código que muestra el problema:

```
import tkinter as tk  

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Lo que se hace aqui no es relevante
        # para el problema

    def p1():
        global n
        n = 1

    def p2():
        global n
        n = n + 2

    # Y así en varias funciones más
```

Comment: lee [ask] para que recibas ayuda de la comunidad, deberás editar tu pregunta y añadir lo que llevas de otro modo será muy difícil recibas ayuda

Comment: Perdón por no poner el código, puse la pregunta para ver si alguien podía entenderme así no más porque no tenía el código. Pero aquí está: https://pastebin.com/JZBH0djY cada clase es una pantalla, las funciones están en la primera clase. Todas tienen el global n, pero falta definir n, pero como ya dije si la definimos me imprime el valor de la definición y no el  de la función. Gracias por su atención.

Comment: @NicolásArévalo Ok. Me he permitido editar tu pregunta para añadir un trozo de código que muestra el problema, para que quien lea la pregunta no tenga que andar buscándolo en los comentarios ni se tenga que leer el pastebin completo, pues la mayoría no está relacionado con lo que preguntas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En general, usar una variable global no es buena idea. Al final de esta respuesta te daré una alternativa.

Pero si quieres usar una variable global, el problema con tu código es que ¡no hay tal variable!

Cuando dentro de una función pones `global n`, básicamente le dices a python que, si la función en algún momento intenta cambiar el valor de un símbolo llamado `n`, el intérprete no debe crear una variable local con ese nombre (que es lo que haría por defecto si no hubieras puesto `global n`). En su lugar, debe usar la variable global llamada `n`. Pero esa variable no existe en tu código.

Basta que la añadas. Por ejemplo, antes del  `class SampleApp` pones

```
n = 0
```

Eso ya creará la variable global, con un valor inicial de `0`. Cuando las funciones que declaran `global n` modifiquen el valor de `n`, lo harán de esa variable global.

Observa que no basta con que la variable exista. Además las funciones deben declararla como global, pues si no cuando por ejemplo `p1()` hace `n=1`, se crearía  una variable local en esa función que no afectaría a la global (además la variable local se destruye una vez la función termina).

### Alternativa

En lugar de variables globales puedes usar atributos del objeto. Un atributo de un objeto es similar a una variable, pero que pertenece sólo a ese objeto. Se usan escribiendo `self.n` por ejemplo.

No obstante en tu caso particular, usar este enfoque te obligaría a cambiar bastantes cosas en el código. Cada una de las funciones `p1()`, `p2()`, etc. deberían declarar un parámetro `self` para poder actuar sobre `self.n`, pero eso cambiaría la forma en que luego enlazas esos métodos con los botones de tu GUI, ya que tal como lo tienes haces `command=SampleApp.p1`, por ejemplo, por lo que los estás tratando como métodos de clase y no de objeto. En su lugar deberías poner `command=controller.p1` y así con todas las demás (ya que `controller` es el objeto instancia de la clase `SampleApp`).

Repito que aunque esto es más correcto, en tu caso puede resultarte más confuso ya que a la vista de tu código se aprecia que no entiendes correctamente los conceptos de programación orientada a objetos.

## Actualización

Tras comentarios adicionales del usuario, parece que el problema no estaba solo en el uso de esa variable global, sino en que al mostrar esa variable al final del programa parecía no haber cambiado de valor.

El hecho es que la variable se muestra en una etiqueta, la cual forma parte de un *frame* que se crea al iniciar el programa. La etiqueta toma una copia del valor que `n` tiene en ese momento, y ya que estamos al principio su valor es 0. Aunque después se modifique el valor de `n`, la etiqueta sigue teniendo su valor original 0, hasta que es mostrada al final del todo.

Lo cierto es que la estructura de tu código es un laberinto... pero sin entrar a rehacerlo todo, tal como lo tienes, lo más sencillo será que cambies lo que muestra esa etiqueta justo antes de mostrarla. Aunque el *frame* se crea al principio, no se muestra hasta el final, y ya que tienes un método específico para mostrar los frames, puede ser ahí donde mires si el frame a mostrar es el último y en ese caso le cambies el texto a la etiqueta por el valor que `n` tenga en ese instante.

Este sería el nuevo método `show_frame()`:

```
  def show_frame(self, page_name):
      '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
      frame = self.frames[page_name]
      if page_name == "LastPage":
        frame.children["resultado"]["text"] = n
      frame.tkraise()
```

Como ves, miramos si `page_name` es `"LastPage"`, y entonces antes de mostrar ese frame, usamos `frame.children` para acceder a sus "hijos" (las etiquetas y botones que lo componen) y seleccionamos el hijo llamado  `"resultado"` (que será la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de `n`), y cambiamos su texto por el valor que `n` tiene en ese momento.

En la clase `LastPage`, cuando creas esa etiqueta debes darle el nombre `"resultado"`, para que el código anterior funcione. Así:

```
      total = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white", name="resultado",
                       text=n, font=controller.title_font)
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por el comentario. Tienes razón al decir que no entiendo mucho aún; a penas estoy comenzando. Disculpa la ignorancia pero es que ya definí la variable y sucede el problema que dije, que al final me imprime el cero con el que fue definida. Y lo de controller.n lo tengo en mi código pero no lo entiendo muy bien.

Comment: No puedo tratar de ejecutar tu código porque me faltan imágenes. En todo caso, ¿dónde dices que te imprime el valor cero? No veo ningún `print()` en tu programa. Sospecho que te refieres al _label_ que creas en la clase `LastPage`, donde copias el valor de `n`. El problema es que esa clase la creas al inicio del programa, cuando `n` vale 0, y por tanto con ese valor se queda el label. Debes actualizar el label (volver a crearlo), o retrasar la creación de `LastPage` hasta el momento en que `n` tiene el valor final.

Comment: Sí, el print es del label de _LastPage_, pero aún no entiendo qué es lo que debo hacer? ¿Cómo retraso la creación de _LastPage_? ¿Cómo lo vuelvo a crear? Porque da igual  que lo cree de nuevo si la variable sigue ahí... Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @NicolásArévalo He actualizado la respuesta con una idea que creo podría resolverte el problema.

Comment: Gracias. Funcionó perfecto.