# pyhton - Imprimir variable global a través de una función

Tags: python, funciones, variables-globales

Tengo los siguientes archivos: `variables.py`, `funciones.py` y `main.py`:

```
# variables.py
variable1 = 'otro texto'
variable2 = 'Valor de Variable.PY'


# funciones.py
from variables import *

def funcionA():
    global variable2
    global variable1
    variable1 = 'texto: ' + variable2
    print(variable1)


# main.py
from variables import *
import funciones

variable2 = 'Hola 4'

funciones.funcionA()
```

`funcionA()` debería imprimir `texto: Hola 4`, pero me está imprimiendo `texto: Valor de Variable.PY`.

Encontré las siguientes páginas pero no comprendí bien...
*[¿Cómo modifico una variable global desde una función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248371/c%c3%b3mo-modifico-una-variable-global-desde-una-funci%c3%b3n)* y *[Modificar una variable global desde una función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212603/modificar-una-variable-global-desde-una-funci%c3%b3n)*

Mi entendimiento es... si desde `main.py` estoy escribiendo una variable global (`variable2`), ¿por qué no la está tomando `funcionA()` si desde `funcionA()` (archivo `funciones.py`) estoy mencionando que voy a "sobreescribir la variable global"?

Gracias por el apoyo que pueda recibir en el tema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### variables globales y su alcance

En Python, las variables globales son a nivel de script, es decir, que existen globalmente en el script donde fueron creadas y no más allá.
Esto implica que cada script tiene sus propias variables globales por separado de los demás scripts.
Sin embargo, los scripts también son objetos y podemos acceder a sus variables globales en forma de atributos

Este import:

```
from variables import *
```

Resulta equivalente a hacer:

```
import variables

variable1 = variables.variable1
variable2 = variables.variable2

del variables
```

Vamos a llamar a este ejemplo "main.py".

Como podrás ver, estás creando variables globales en `main` que se llaman igual a las variables en el modulo `variables`.
Ahora, notarás que alterar variable2 como hiciste, solo altera a la variable2 del script `main`, no a la variable "original".

##### Solución

Una forma de acceder en tiempo real a las variables almacenadas en el script, es obtener el objeto que lo representa y acceder a los valores mediante atributos. Esto se puede lograr usando `import [script]`

Tu código de ejemplo, dejando inalterado variables.py quedaría así:

```
# funciones.py
import variables

def funcionA():
    variables.variable1 = 'texto: ' + variables.variable2
    print(variables.variable1)


# main.py
import variables
import funciones

variables.variable2 = 'Hola 4'

funciones.funcionA()
```

Notas adicionales:

- No te preocupes por que se creen varios objetos que representen al script, Python tiene un cache que hace que el mismo objeto se reutilice luego de que es importado por primera vez.
- Si el nombre te parece muy largo y no querés cambiar de nombre al script variables, podés agregar a tu import  `as [nombre]`, para determinar cual va a ser el nombre de la variable en la que el script se guarde.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación, me queda claro y ya entiendo porqué no se alteraba el resultado. Saludos.